# How to properly package loadCSS and cssrelpreload using webpack 2?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to package [filamentgroup/loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) using webpack 2 but I fail to do so. I'd like to get [cssrelpreload.js](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/src/cssrelpreload.js) executed in the browser so it preloads CSS files for browsers which do not support `rel="preload"`.

I've tried using `imports-loader` and `exports-loader` to have `window.loadCSS` available for `cssrelpreload.js` but I'm unable configure it correctly.

I was able to get `window` available for `loadCSS.js`, but that doesn't help to get `cssrelpreload.js` executed correctly.

How would I need to configure webpack to get this packaged correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
import { loadCSS } from 'fg-loadcss';
loadCSS( 'style.css' );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Unfortunately that's no what I meant. I don't need to use `loadCSS` directly, I only want to include `cssrelpreload.js`, which depends on `loadCSS.js`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`import cssrelpreload from 'fg-loadcss/src/cssrelpreload.js'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars`

I've added `eslint-disable-line` because we don't use that imported var.